# F#: Member constraints to help create seemingly dynamic types

Tags: generics, f#, generic-constraints

I've been looking into a way to add some duck typing to an F# method.

```
SomeMethod(model:'a) =
   let someField = model.Test("")
```

Where the parameter coming in has the Test method on it.  I've seen notation like this:

```
member inline public x.Testing< ^a when ^a : (member public Test : String-> String)>(model:^a) =   
  let something = model.Test("")
  ignore
```

Which looks like to me that generic constraints can be used to enfore at a method level rather than class/interface level.  Problem is I can't get it to compile due to type issues.  This leads me to believe that there isn't a way to specify constraints at the method level.  Is that coorect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for this is a bit clunky, but here it is.

```
type Foo() =
  member inline public x.Testing(model) =   
    let something = (^a : (member Test : string -> string) (model, ""))
    ignore
```

You're probably better off using an interface:

```
type IModel
  abstract Test : string -> string
```